# How can I capture a key press, outside of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

I have been trying to capture the keys pressed outside of my winform, but obviously a KeyPress event won't work.

I haven't been able to get any closer than the KeyPress event, which only works on the form level, as specified

I suspect that I will have to do the

> [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]

, but I have little to no experience with that.

Comment: Your best bet is to run your application on DOS.  Then you can read keystrokes any time you want :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being able to capture key presses anywhere requires using [Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There is a library on CodePlex which simplifies implementing [Application and Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) for C# users.

Comment: Your second link is now dead.

Comment: The project has moved to: https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook