# KeyEventArgs to Timer.Tick

Tags: c#

I try to get KeyEventArgs to Tick. If someone thinks why I'm using timer, so it needs to detect keypress outside of window too.

I don't have "error" in this code, but when I run program comes:

`Exception Unhandled. System.NullReferenceExpetion: (i try to translate) 'Your object referral can't define object occurrence'`

Now thing what I'm using is

```html
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            A.Start();
            A.Interval = 1;
        }

private void A_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            KeyEventArgs ke = e as KeyEventArgs;
            if (ke.KeyCode == Keys.R) 
            {
            test = true;     
            }       
        }
```

I really need help, because this error has been so long time. Thanks

Comment: `ok` is probably null and accessing `ok.KeyCode` is probably throwing the null reference exception. `EventArgs e` can't be cast to `KeyEventArgs` for some reason most likely. Also, what are you trying to do here? Why do you have KeyEventArgs in a tick event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What triggers A_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: John Form load runs A_Tick.

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171081/how-can-i-capture-a-key-press-outside-of-the-form

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the way you put your question together to me it seems you're trying to detect a key press using a timer. Instead you can use the Form's KeyPress event.

Use:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.SOMETHING)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set `KeyPreview = true;` for the Form.

**EDIT:** If you need to detect keypresses even without focus(outside of the form), you need a global hotkey by hooking. You need the following:

First include this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

You need this at very top of your class:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
const int HOTKEY = 1;
```

And you need to call this inside Form's Load:

```
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, HOTKEY, (uint)ModifierKeys.SOMETHING, (uint) Keys.SOMETHING);
```

Then you need to handle the press:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == HOTKEY) 
    {
        //do something when pressed
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Does this work outside of form? Because it need to work.

Comment: @HappyFrog: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: @HappyFrog I've updated my answer with an EDIT included that demonstrates how to detect keypresses outside of the form (not focused).

Comment: What I put to: RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, HOTKEY, (uint)ModifierKeys.**HERE**, (uint)         because it does not accept key.

Comment: @HappyFrog If you don't want modifierkeys then use ModifierKeys.None.

Comment: Nope. Comes error if i put there anything. Error says "Member 'Keys.None' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"